# How Do I query a particular field in the below document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB documents as below.

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65a005edaf45cf346a037c10112"
  },
  "performance_data": {
    "campaign.accessible_bidding_strategy": "customers/41594039855/accessibleBiddingStrategies/8763515023",
    "campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status": "OPTIMIZE"
    }
},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65a005edaf45cf346a037c10112"
  },
  "performance_data": {
    "campaign.accessible_bidding_strategy": "customers/41594039855/accessibleBiddingStrategies/8763515023",
    "campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status": "ACTIVE"
    }
}
```

I want to return a document where "campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status" is "Active". I tried using the following filter but it doesn't work.

```
{"performance_data.campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status":"ACTIVE"}
```

The reason it don't work is because the column name in my document contains a Dot Operator as a part of its naming convention. But when I add the column name in Mongo Compass filter it considers the dot on the column name as nested object and try to find the ad_serving_optimization_status inside campaign object and look for campaign object inside performance_data object.

Ideally, it should look for a key/column "campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status" in a performance_data object. How do I make MongoDB understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right that the dot in the field name makes the filter  `{"performance_data.campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status":"ACTIVE"}` ambiguous.

Note that you are trying to get the query executor to treat the 2 dots in the same filter expression differently.

The most robust solution would be to restructure the schema so the field does not contain a dot, perhaps

```
{ 
  "_id": { "$oid": "65a005edaf45cf346a037c10112" }, 
  "performance_data": { 
    "campaign_accessible_bidding_strategy": "customers/41594039855/accessibleBiddingStrategies/8763515023",
    "campaign_ad_serving_optimization_status": "OPTIMIZE" 
  } 
},
```

or

```
{ 
  "_id": { "$oid": "65a005edaf45cf346a037c10112" }, 
  "performance_data": { 
    "campaign": {
        "accessible_bidding_strategy": "customers/41594039855/accessibleBiddingStrategies/8763515023",
        "ad_serving_optimization_status": "OPTIMIZE" 
    }
  } 
},
```

The documentation suggests using `$getField`, which might look like:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "campaign.ad_serving_optimization_status",
          "input": "$performance_data"
        }
      },
      "ACTIVE"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LwvVjDs0A5X)

While that does technically work, it would not be serviced by an index.